# problem with sorting and number generation in python 3

Tags: python, arrays, sorting, random

I wrote a program for generating and sorting numbers, but it does not work after firing, nothing is displayed, I also wanted these numbers to sort and also does not work. I drank 3 coffee and then nothing.

```
import random
mylist = []
for i in range(0,5):
  x = random.randint(1,50)
  mylist.append(x)
  mylist.sort()
```

I tried to give *mylist.sort ()* functions in different places, I tried without it and then nothing.

I am just learning and maybe this problem is not difficult but at the beginning of my career everything is complicated.

Comment: after the for loop, add `print(mylist)`

Comment: your code is working fine to my end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's working fine. You may be missed to print your list to see your output.

```
import random
mylist = []
for i in range(0, 5):
    x = random.randint(1, 50)
    mylist.append(x)
    mylist.sort()
print(mylist)
```

Output

```
[1, 6, 11, 32, 46]
```

If you say about descent code and complexity then it should use sort function outside of the loop.'

```
    import random
    mylist = []
    for i in range(0, 5):
        x = random.randint(1, 50)
        mylist.append(x)
    mylist.sort() # also can use sorted(mylist)
    print(mylist)
```

Comment: mylist.sort() should better be at the end rather than in the `for`-loop, though.

Comment: @Stef yes agree! I just fixed his issue but it works. If you say about descent code and complexity then I agree with you to sort outside of loop.

Answer (score -1):

This hopefully works

The first reason it didn't work, because list.sort() only sorts the list but doesn't return or print it. However sorted(list) sorts it and returns the sorted version.

Also it is better to do the sorting outside the for loop otherwise it will happen at each step.

```
import random
mylist = []
for i in range(0,5):
  x = random.randint(1,50)
  mylist.append(x)
mylist = sorted(mylist)
print(mylist)

Output: [3, 20, 26, 32, 39]
```

Comment: One obvious remark is that your code replaces `.sort` with `sorted`, which means the original list is not sorted; but the return value of `sorted` is ignored in your code, so the sorted copy of the list is thrown out immediately. If your code was copy-pasted into the python REPL, then the REPL would manage to salvage the sorted copy of the list returned by `sorted` and print it to screen; but otherwise your code is just keeping the shuffled list and not producing any sorted output.

Comment: Hi Stef, thank you very much for your explanation and kind reply. Best